# How to pick your victim?

Tags: the-castle-doctrine

The list of targets as shown in the screenshot below unfortunately starts at the highest value target which is very likely to be unsurvivable for a new player. Picking the lowest fund target may also fail since these may just have spent most of their funds on very sophisticated traps. So what are good indicators of manageable thefts?

[image: target list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It costs you nothing to rob a house, as long as you don't bring anything with you and you emerge with your skin intact. While the presence of money and high kill counts can indicate a particularly lethal or difficult house layout, it's far more important to just get your feet in the door so you can begin assessing the house as a target.

To begin a career in home invasion, you really need to master the identification of commit traps. Consider the following pair that I've constructed for this illustration:

[image: two simple commit traps]

First, the metal grating is safe to step on initially, but once you move past it, it electrifies, making it impossible to return the direction you came without disabling some aspect of this construction. Similarly, it's possible to pass the pit bull safely, but if you continue along the path to the top, the dog will be two steps behind you the entire way. Either way, you're now committed to the path toward the vault—or to a dead end that you didn't know about.

The reason it's so important to be able to identify commit traps is so that you can tell exactly how far you can move safely into the property without making it impossible to escape. With this in mind, it's possible now to generalize the way you go about deciding whether a house is worth the effort:

1. Bring nothing with you on your first foray into the home. Use this trip to identify any initial commit traps; figure out what kind of tools you'd need to brute-force your way into the house's later defenses.
2. As long as the home's potential for profit exceeds the cost of the tools you'll use to crack it, it's a worthwhile target. Bare in mind that EVERY tool you bring with you on ANY trip into the house is a sunk cost; whether you get to the vault or flee in failure, you aren't getting those tools back.
3. If it makes sense to pursue this house as a target, buy your equipment and get to work! Do everything you can to figure out how this house ticks, how you can brute-force your way through if necessary, and ABOVE ALL, **DON'T GET TRAPPED.** If you find you've sunk a lot of money into brute-forcing your way through some of the house's defenses, you might consider whether it's viable offing one of the owner's family members; any time you kill the wife or one of the children, all changes you've made to the house are recorded for future attempts. (Unless and until the homeowner can make repairs.)
4. Iterate the last two steps as necessary. There may come a point where it's apparent that a house will cost more money to break than you have available, or it will cost more than it's worth. The sooner you can recognize that this point is going to arrive, the more money you can save by cutting your losses and moving on to another target.
5. With that, you should be well on your way to making money at robbery! Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

The monetary value of a house is the sum of the money in the vault and the wife's possession plus the value of tools in the vault. So a low value is at least an indication on the funds the owner was able to invest into their security.

However, a the two numbers next to the value are probably slightly more helpful: The first one shows the total amount of attempted thefts at that house and the second one the total amount of deaths, i.e. failures. The quotient of deaths divided by attempts gives you a rough estimate for the probability of failing. However, note that the number does not include failures that managed to escape alive and that the house owner might meanwhile have increased their security, so just because a house has zero deaths so far that doesn't mean you won't be its first victim...

Finally, you can have a look at your security tapes to see what kinds of tools robbers at your house were using. While it's a far shot, you may be able to guess about their own thoughts on security. And remember, even when you died, you can write down the randomized names of others so you can retry *their* house specifically, hoping they didn't change too much about it.